# C++ Setup in Visual Studio Code fails to run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded VSC in order to start learning C++. Previously I had just used Notepad++ for web design and Python IDE for Python, but I decided to move onto Visual Studio Code for a more sophisticated code editor.

However, when trying to run a basic program, I don't have the option to run in the first place. This picture is what's supposed to come up when you right-click on the text area (from multiple YouTube tutorials):

[image]

However, this is what comes up on my screen.

[image]

Additionally, there is no "run" button on the top-right of the screen like the tutorials show.

My folders regarding VSC in File Explorer are quite simple. I have a folder for my .cpp code, and MinGW as a compiler. My build is Windows 10.

Obviously, this depends from person to person, but is there any key way this situation can be resolved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the c++ extensions for vscode as well? If you're new to programming/vscode, its best follow a guide, c++ in vscode requires quite a bit of setup to get working smoothly. The official documentation should work fine https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Comment: *I just downloaded VSC in order to start learning C++.* -- Maybe it would have been better to simply download `Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition` instead.  If you're just learning C++, the better option to me would be to install something that requires little, if any setup, that comes with the Visual C++ 2019 compiler.